# acts as tenant gem scopes all users data, ignoring scoping data based on the subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multi-tenant, acts-as-tenant

I am using acts_as_tenant gem to do a multi-tenant app. I followed the instructions. I am using sub-domains.

In my `application_controller.rb` I have:

`set_current_tenant_by_subdomain(:account, :subdomain)`

I am using `Account` as the tenant. In my `User` model I called:

```
acts_as_tenant(:account)
```

**The Problem**

When I log into an account using a subdomain (e.g: `john.realestate.dev`), everything is OK (`current_tenant` i.e john is set).

I have another model called `Property`; when the current logged in tenant i.e john creates a new property, that record is seen by all the other users. I want only john to be able see the record he has created.

Where am I going wrong?

my models relationships are:-

`Account` - `has_many :users`

`User` - `belongs_to :account`

`Property`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i fixed my issue by creating a relationship between Account(has_many :properties) and Property(Belongs_to :account).

then i added   acts_as_tenant(:account) to the Property Model. I ran a migration that adds account_id to the property model.

now it scopes data only created by the logged in user according to the subdomain.

i fixed it by re-reading the gem's doc multiple times until i made sense of this statement from the doc.

> acts_as_tenant requires each scoped model to have a column in its schema linking it to a tenant. Adding acts_as_tenant to your model declaration will scope that model to the current tenant BUT ONLY if a current tenant has been set.

Any ideas, suggestions on my implementation are mob welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The real fix here is to make sure you include `acts_as_tenant(:account)` on every single model you want scoped. 
This is going to make sure it checks for the `current_tenant` before saving data.

You don't necessarily need the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relation, although it sounds like it may make sense for your application.